# Is there a way to show development build files in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to use the create-react-app in an existing app without using the default index.html built in that links the scripts generated by running `yarn start`. These files include `/static/js/bundle.js`, `static/js/0.chunk.js`, `static/js/main.chunk.js`, and `/main.somehash...hot-update.js`

I set `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` in my `.env` but no files ever get generated in the static folder when running `yarn start`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either eject your project or use react-app-rewired to customize your webpack configuration. This way, you can modify the path to output js.